# QCameraImageCapture() no matching function

Tags: qt, camera

I get the error,

```
error: no matching function for call to 'QCameraImageCapture::QCameraImageCapture()'
```

Simply by having the code,

```
#include <QCamera>
#include <QCameraImageCapture>

class Webcam : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Webcam();mageCaptured();

private:
    QCameraImageCapture _imageCamera;
};
```

I have written no other code. Any idea what's going on here? It worked for QCamera _camera;

EDIT:

Sorry, this is completely my fault. Too much time using Python made me forget all about pointers.

Comment: What does pointer have to do with this issue?

Answer (score 2):

`QCameraImageCapture` doesn't have a default constructor, see the documentation [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qcameraimagecapture.html#QCameraImageCapture), so you must pass a `QMediaObject` pointer to the constructor of `QCameraImageCapture` (`QCamera` inherits from `QMediaObject` so it can be used there)

Quote from documentation:

> The QCameraImageCapture class is a high level images recording class. It's not intended to be used alone but for accessing the media recording functions of other media objects, like QCamera.